# In Rails, how do I nest custom routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have 3 resources.

- `Projects`
- `Books`
- `Chapters`

`Projects` and `Books` are many_to_many through `ProjectBooks`, `Books` have_many `Chapters`, which belong_to `Books`.

I easily can set up basic routes for `/projects/1` and `/books/2` and `/chapters/3`.

How do I list just the `Books` that are attached to a given project? How do I add information about those `Books` that is relevant to that `Project`?

Thus, my routes should be:

- `/books/2` - show book 2
- `/projects/1` - show project 1
- `/projects/1/books` - list books in project 1 and additional information
- `/projects/1/books/2/chapters` - information about chapters in book 2 relevant to project 1

My original thought was custom routes with a `books` method on my `ProjectsController`. Routing:

```
resources :projects do
  get :books, on: :member
end
```

But that doesn't let me get `/projects/1/books/2/chapters`.

Then I thought about embedded resources:

```
resources :projects, param: :name do
  resources :books do
    resources :chapters
  end
end
```

Which works, but instead of calling `projects#books` it calls `books#index`, which really lists all of the books, and gives me no way to get `#chapters` in the context of a project.

How do I handle the twin challenges of:

1. `Books` can be listed independently but also in the context of a `Project`
2. Adding specific information when listed in the context of a `Project`

EDIT:

My assumption is that only `ProjectsController` can discover which `Books` are part of this project, and certainly only `ProjectsController` knows how to add `Project`-specific data like statistics. If my assumptions are off and there is a different way to structure this, all for it.

Comment: What are you exactly after? The routes you have put in question at the bottom looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Surya In order to list just the `Books` that are connected to this `Project`, and to add relevant data to the view, do I not need a separate action, e.g. `projects#books`? If I do the routing above, it calls `books#index`, which lists all books, and has no idea of the `Project` context. Only the `ProjectsController` has that.

Comment: You can do something like `match '/books/:book_id/chapters' => 'projects#chapters'` for your first approach (having everything in one `ProjectController`)

Comment: Anyway, read this excellent guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. I'm sure you'll find all answers there

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did. Actually, I have it open in the tab right next to stackoverflow. :-) `match` is an interesting solution. I will try that. But I wonder if there is a more 'native' or cleaner way? Or perhaps I simply am structuring my controllers incorrectly?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that worked. Put it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

You can do something like

```
match '/books/:book_id/chapters' => 'projects#chapters'
```

for your first approach (having everything in one `ProjectController`)

More info is in the [Rails Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

EDIT (by OP):

I used your answer and did a slight variant:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get 'books', to: 'projects#books'
    get 'books/:book_id/chapters', to: 'projects#chapters'
    get 'books/:book_id/chapters/:chapter_id/units', to: 'projects#units'
  end
end
```

Putting it inside of the `:projects` resources made it easier to manage.

Comment: It worked. I did a slight variant, I will edit your answer to show how I applied it. Thanks, Sergio!